# tomcat server started but localhost:8080 is not up

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, solr

I am following the tomcat installation using sysdeo plugin for eclipse in the following link:

http://technologicaloddity.com/using-projects/java-projects/setting-up-the-sysdeo-tomcat-plug-in/

Since i have the requirement of running solrserver within tomcat from my spring mvc, i follwed the above link.

I configured everything,also i did solr war deployment confs and started tomcat.there is no more errors in console and it says server started,solr war also gets deployed,i could see the files inside tomcat directory.but still when i check the url

> localhost:8080

it does not showing tomcat home page.also,

> localhost:8080/solr

does not takes me to solr admin page
I am using tomcat 7.0.37,solr-1.4.0,eclipse indigo 64 bit in windows 7.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the real tomcat installation/path or you link your project into the tomcat?
On the server configuration side in eclipse you can select 'use tomcat installation' and then you can see the tomcat root webapp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for ur solution. I made it by just specifying the tomcat base directory to tomcat installation path.actually i have missed that part. now it is working properly.do you have any idea on starting solr server inside tomcat container from within spring web application?

Answer (score 0):

For mac users

First Try : go to activity monitor -> search for java and kill the instance then restart the server and try.

Second Try:
Check log file for any errors under tomcat logs folder.

Use below command to check tomcat logs in terminal

```
tail -f {tomcatpath}/logs/catalina.out
```

Third Try:
Check if node or other apps using the same port. Use below command to check which app listening to a specific port. You will see list of apps with pid in second column.

```
lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN
```

Kill the process using below command

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```